# Insert php code into a flash message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to insert this code into a flash message, but it seems like flash messages do not accept a flash message

```
<?php echo Session::get('notify') ? "<p style='color:green'>" . Session::get('notify') . "</p>" : "" ?>
<h1>Welcome <?php echo $user->username ?></h1>
<p>Your email: <?php echo $user->email ?></p>
<p>Your account was created on: <?php echo $user->created_at ?></p>
?>


Route::post('registration', array('before' => 'csrf',function()
{
    $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|unique:users',
        'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|same:password_confirm'

    );
    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('registration')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
    }

    $user           = new User;
    $user->username = Input::get('username');
    $user->email    = Input::get('email');
    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

    if ($user->save())
    {
        Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
        return Redirect::to('index')->with('flash_message', 'Thank you for registering. {{ echo Session::get('notify') ? "<p style='color:green'>" . Session::get('notify') . "</p>" : "" ?>
            <h1>Welcome <?php echo $user->username ?></h1>
            <p>Your email: <?php echo $user->email ?></p>
            <p>Your account was created on: <?php echo $user->created_at ?></p>
            <p><a href="<?= URL::to('profile-edit') ?>">Edit your information</a></p>}}'
        );
    }
    return Redirect::to('registration')->withInput();
}));
```

How can I do that?

I tried to rename the flash_message and put it under in the master.blade.php like this:

```
@if(Session::get('login_message'))
    <div class='login-message'>{{ Session::get('login_message') }}
        <?php echo Session::get('notify') ? "<p style='color:green'>" . Session::get('notify') . "</p>" : "" ?>
        <h1>Welcome <?php echo $user->username ?></h1>
        <p>Your email: <?php echo $user->email ?></p>
        <p>Your account was created on: <?php echo $user->created_at ?></p>
        <p><a href="<?= URL::to('profile-edit') ?>">Edit your information</a></p> ?>
    </div>
@endif
```

but it did not work, as I guess that I will have to put the php into the routes or into the controller. But I do not know how to do that and I failed to declare the correct variable. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing a few coding styles here, and there are elements of your views in your controller which is confusing matters.

Try passing the variables you want to display to the blade view, and then use the `{{ $variable }}` notation to include them:

In your action, pass your user back to the view:

```
// (snip) 
if ($user->save())
{
    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
    return Redirect::to('index')
                   ->with('login_message', 'Thank you for registering.') 
                   ->with('user', $user);
}
// (snip)
```

and extract those elements of the user (it's all in the `Session` now) in the view:

```
@if(Session::has('login_message'))
    <div class='login-message'>
        {{ Session::get('login_message') }} 
        <h1>Welcome {{ Session::get('user')->username }}</h1>
        <p>Your email: {{ Session::get('user')->email }}</p>
        <p>Your account was created on: {{ Session::get('user')->created_at }}</p>
        <p><a href="{{ URL::to('profile-edit') }}">Edit your information</a></p> ?>
    </div>
@endif
```

That should help you in the right direction.

Comment: ->with('user', $user); is not allowed with Redirect::to as of the post of another user! Is there a way to use xxz::Flash?

Comment: @Thankyou.. sorry, got what you mean now. you need to pull the user from the Session as well as the login_message (`Session::get('user')`).  Updated my answer

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::username() It does not work. Does someone else have a solution?

Comment: @Thankyou Check if you have accidentally added brackets to the end of `Session::get('user')->username` in the View?  It's not there in my answer, and it would give you that error if it was..